# sharekit, change link url when posting image?

Tags: iphone, facebook, sharekit

The image is generated by iphone application.
(The image is not hosted on any web server)

I can post image on facebook with sharekit fine.

=======
 =image=
 =======
[From %Application Title%]

The link[From %Application Title%] goes to 'application' page of facebook.
(http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=.....)

I want the link goes to (http://www.facebook.com/myAppPage) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to upload image with hyperlink. you have to upload image which is present on server. I tried too many ways to upload image with hyperlink using sharekit did not work.